# How do I efficiently replace the last line in a string?

Tags: python

I have a multi-line string, and I would like to replace the last line of the string with a different line. How do I most efficiently do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split on the last linebreak and attach a new line:

```
new = old.rstrip('\n').rsplit('\n', 1)[0] + '\nNew line to be added with line break included.'
```

This first removes any trailing newline after the last line, splits *once* on the last newline in the text, takes everything before that last newline, and concatenates the result with a new newline and text.

Demo:

```
>>> old = '''The quick
... brown fox jumps
... over the lazy
... dog
... '''
>>> old.rstrip('\n').rsplit('\n', 1)[0] + '\nhorse and rider'
'The quick\nbrown fox jumps\nover the lazy\nhorse and rider'
```

This presumes that your lines are separated by `\n` characters; reading text files in text mode gives you such data on any platform.

If you are dealing with data with different line endings, adjust accordingly. In such cases [`os.linesep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep) can come in useful.

Comment: I forgot about the trailing newline, +1!

Comment: I wouldn't strip trailing newlines at all and just consider the last line to be blank in that case.

Comment: @Cairnarvon: That is entirely dependent on context. In that case leave out the `.rstrip()` call and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach:

```
>>> x = """
... test1
... test2
... test3"""
>>> print "\n".join(x.splitlines()[:-1]+["something else"])

test1
test2
something else
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right - my interpretation of "most efficiently" was from the programmer's perspective.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this using a simple regular expressions.

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(r'[^\n]*\n?$', "replacement", "existing\nstring")
```

It matches everything with the exception of the \n at the end of the string and replaces it with the replacement string.

Comment: Using `re` is absolutely the biggest overhead! OP's question was about the **most efficient way** to do this.